# How do I globally serialize and deserialize Date vs DateTime when stored as UTC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, asp.net-web-api, json.net

In my SQL Server database, I store all `DateTime` values as UTC. There are some instances, though, where I do not care about time like when a user in some random timezone selects a date using a DatePicker. In these cases, it seemed to make more sense to just store as `Date` vs `DateTime`.

When getting the dates out of the database and sending them down to my Angular app through Web API, I wanted to ensure all my `DateTime` values were formatted in a way so that Angular would know they were UTC dates and display as local time so I added this to Web API to add the "Z" at the end:

```
// Set all dates to UTC
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
});
```

This works, but the problem is that this conversion is also being applied to my `Date` values as well. When a date is pulled from the database into C#, they are in `DateTime` variables as C# doesn't have a `Date` variable so they get a time of midnight. So if a user in CST picks a date of 11/24/2018, when it goes round-trip to the database and back, it becomes 11/23/2018 (with the time of 6:00pm truncated).

How can I prevent this behavior? Some ideas could be:

1. Conditionally apply the IsoDateTimeConverter?

   - I don't think this is possible globally since I wouldn't be able to tell if it was a `Date` or `DateTime` value stored in the C# DateTime variable.
2. Change the datatype in SQL Server to `DateTime`?

   - I don't think this would work either because even if I stored the time based on where the data originated, couldn't it still be wrong for users in other timezones?

Comment: BTW you can use DateTimeFormat "o" for ISO8601 format dates. That doesn't help much with your question, of course.

Comment: Since you're using JSON.NET, you could maybe use the [JsonConverter] attribute on just those date fields. I'd be interested to see if there's a better solution.

Comment: @John, I thought about doing that. I'd prefer to handle it globally if possible. If I did end up doing this, do you know if the attribute would override the global IsoDateTimeConverter so I can still use the global converter for all other DateTime values?

Comment: I believe it should do, but don't hold me to that.

Comment: Are you able to use DateTimeOffset as a datatype?  That should offer you the ultimate in flexibility where the date is always the date.

Comment: First, it seems that you are confusing [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The first is a special Time Zone, the second one is a standard specification of string representations of date / time / datetime  and periods. Second, If you are working with Sql Server, [you should be using `DateTime2`, and not `DateTime`.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnsoldevs/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/)

Comment: Also, this part seems wrong to me: "So if a user in CST picks a date of 11/24/2018, when it goes round-trip to the database and back, it becomes 11/23/2018 (with the time of 6:00pm truncated)." When you select data with type `Date` from the database into c#, you get the correct date at midnight. How did you get from 11/24 to 11/23?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I meant round-trip all the way to the client. The date is correct in C#, but when the Web API global converter which is meant for `DateTime` fields is also applied to `Date` fields, then Angular's `NativeDateAdapter` (which uses the JavaScript Date object) adjusts midnight to local time, which results in the displayed date being incorrect.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, from the ISO8601 wiki page in your comment, it says "If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset." This is exactly why I'm using the global converter, because I want all my DateTime values which are stored as UTC to conform to ISO8601 so they render correctly on the client. So I'm not sure what you mean when you say I'm confusing the two. Also, thanks for the tip about DateTime2, I always forget about it, although I'm unclear how it would help with the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Well, if c# gets it correctly then the problem is elsewhere. I know nothing on angular but I would start by asking why it is converting the value from UTC to local time zone. I thought you where confusing the two because you wrote "...DateTime values were formatted as UTC...".

Answer (score 2):

Using @John's suggestion, I created a custom IsoDateTimeConverter:

```
public class DateConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy";
    }
}
```

And manually applied it to each `Date` value which overrides the global converter I added to the Web API config.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DateConverter))]
public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

I'm still hoping there's a global way of handling this instead of having to apply the attribute to each `Date` property, but this at least gets me unstuck.

A **warning** to Angular users. I originally tried to use the format "yyyy-MM-dd", but it must interpret that as UTC because I had the same issue when the date was shown to the user. Changing it to "MM-dd-yyyy" worked though. See https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6111

Comment: I think you've got the right solution. If your classes used a different data type for `Date` versus `DateTime` to mirror the DB then you could use a custom converter targeted at that type in your global config (alongside the other converter for DateTime) and you would not need the attributes. But since they use the same data type, you still need some kind of attribute to differentiate them in order to be able to apply a converter globally (e.g. using a custom contract resolver). So you might as well just use the `[JsonConverter]` attribute to apply the converter directly and skip the resolver.